# How to filter out nested array of obj

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

This is my data:

```js
{
  "productGroups": [
    {
      "selectedProducts": [
        { "productPricing": { "recurringFee": {}, "oneTimeFee": {} }, "id": "610e99f9b13b4126a9e07e36" }
      ]
    },
    {
      "selectedProducts": [
        { "productPricing": { "recurringFee": {}, "oneTimeFee": {} } }
      ]
    },
    {
      "selectedProducts": [
        { "productPricing": { "recurringFee": {}, "oneTimeFee": {} } }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to remove array element if there is no selectedProducts.id

so result should be:

```js
{
  "productGroups": [
    {
      "selectedProducts": [
        { "productPricing": { "recurringFee": {}, "oneTimeFee": {} }, "id": "610e99f9b13b4126a9e07e36" }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This is what i tried:

```js
const filteredData = {
  productGroups: data.productGroups.map(productGroup => {
    const selectedProduct = productGroup.selectedProducts?.filter(product => product.id);
    return selectedProduct;
  }),
};
```

My result is wrong and I get result with empty arrays:

```js
{
  "productGroups": [
    [
      { "productPricing": { "recurringFee": {}, "oneTimeFee": {} }, "id": "610e9a5eb13b4126a9e07e37" }],
    [],
    []
  ]
}
```

Comment: Why did you choose [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)? Did you have a look at the other methods of an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let data = {
  "productGroups": [
    {
      "selectedProducts": [
        { "productPricing": { "recurringFee": {}, "oneTimeFee": {} }, "id": "610e99f9b13b4126a9e07e36" }
      ]
    },
    {
      "selectedProducts": [
        { "productPricing": { "recurringFee": {}, "oneTimeFee": {} } }
      ]
    },
    {
      "selectedProducts": [
        { "productPricing": { "recurringFee": {}, "oneTimeFee": {} } }
      ]
    }
  ]
};


const filteredData = {
  productGroups: data.productGroups.filter(productGroup => {
    const selectedProduct = productGroup.selectedProducts.filter(product => product.id);
      return selectedProduct.length;
  }),
};


console.log(JSON.stringify(filteredData))
```

Comment: If a `selectedProduct` array has elements with and without ids they will still be included.

Comment: can you explain how selectedProduct.length works? @norbert.mate

Comment: since your inner `filter` isn't actually filtering anything it would be more efficient to just use a `some()`. Some exits early, while filter by necessity iterates all elements. `productGroups: data.productGroups.filter(({ selectedProducts }) => selectedProducts.some(({ id }) => id !== undefined)),`

Comment: @pilchard I see what you mean and it makes sense but Emilis asked for: "remove array element if there is no selectedProducts.id"

Comment: @Emilis if there is no element with id the array will be empty so the length will be 0. Array filter works by checking if the returned value is true/false. In this case 0 will be evaluated as false.

Comment: I understand how you are using filter() and my proposed use of `some()` achieves the same thing without having to look at every element.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
const filteredData = {
  productGroups: data.productGroups.filter(productGroup => {
     return (productGroup.selectedProducts.filter((product) => (product.id !== undefined && product.id != '') ? true: false)).length;
  }),
};
```